# what's the process state when a erlang process is running `receive after`?

Tags: erlang

I want know the the erlang process state when this process is running `receive after`:

```
receive
  X ->
    ok
after 1000 ->
   ok
end
```

1、Is the process state is running or waiting?

2、Does this process will use cpu schedler time?

3、If i have 120000 erlang process like this, every process will run code like this:

```
receive
      X ->
        ok
    after 1000 ->
       ok
end
```

So, Does this code will be a bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

The process is just moving along with whatever comes after the receive expression.

For example, let's say a inline a request/response:

```
ask_foo(SomePID) ->
    Ref = make_ref(),
    SomePID ! {self(), Ref, why},
    receive
        {Ref, Answer} ->
            io:format("The answer: ~tp~n", [Answer])
      after
        1000 ->
            io:format("~p is too slow. Moving on...~n", [SomePID])
    end,
    io:format("I'll print this in any case, and then exit.").
```

`receive` blocks until it either receives a message that *matches* one of its receive clauses, *or* the timeout occurs -- whichever happens first. Then it continues on doing whatever else is in its code. Very often there is a single `receive` loop, but it is not uncommon to use a series of inline `receive` clauses for things that should block, like [waiting on a fixed sequence of inputs from a user](https://github.com/zxq9/erlmud/blob/master/erlmud-0.1/telcon.erl#L34-L39) or something similar.

The "process's state" is not changing in terms of its *state data* at all. It *is* blocking -- which means it is suspended until a message or a timeout occurrs. But, unlike polling systems, this does not carry an overhead penalty with it because the VM is managing the scheduling (the process doesn't have to wake itself up, it can safely block on `receive`).

You asked if this will be a bottleneck: No. No other processes are blocking, only *this* one. All other processes are executing on their *own* schedule, and they have nothing to do with this one. So when blocking on a receive you are only holding up the rest of the things this particular process is supposed to do. Whether or not that is a bottleneck becomes, therefore, an architectural question.

Comment: what the situation: the 12000 process run `receive after` at the same time, is this a bottleneck? i mean `at the same time`.

Comment: @BlackMamba 12,000 processes blocking on receive at once is the same as 100,000 blocking on receive at once. That is not any overhead. If they *all* receive a message or timeout at the exact same time, then you will have a heavy load on the *execution* of the relevant statements, but blocking on receive itself is not a heavy overhead. Ticking 12,000 `after` timers at once might have an overhead -- but I think this actually affects you in a weird way: the timers will not all *effectively* wind up being 1000 milliseconds because tripping them all at once will cause contention.

Comment: Another question: when a process run `receive afer`, it's state is `blocking`,  how the erlang schedular to handle this process?

Comment: @BlackMamba A process waiting on a message is not scheduled until it has a new message in its mailbox. This is a reactive activity, not a polling activity -- which is why this is not adding overhead to a running node. There are some details to how this works, though, but getting further into it really calls for a new question. The basic case is that any process blocking on `receive` is simply not scheduled at all until a message for it is received.